# Amazon MWS - missing BuyerTaxInfo in getOrder API Call

Tags: amazon-mws

When I call the getOrder API the response is very different from documentation, in particular I'm trying to get the Object BuyerTaxInfo (to get company legal name and tax id) but the object is always missing from the response (both from SDK and Scratchpad) instead there is another object TaxRegistrationDetails, which is not on the documentations that contains tax id but not company legal name.

How am I supposed to get the correct object/response?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to apply for access to TAXEL and FUL. That is what will allow you to see it in the MWS scratchpad.

Secondly, after your access has been approved. download the last dll from MWS documentation. When you will make the call for LISTORDERS and GETORDER, you will receive the;  **TaxRegistrationDetails** not the "BUYERTAXINFO". I am afraid that buyertaxinfo, is not longer being returned by MWS and it has been substituted by **TaxRegistrationDetails**.

Do not expect any help from MWS team, absolutely useless and they will waste your precious time.

I am attaching the response from a customer who had a TAX ID.

```
<TaxRegistrationDetails>
    <member>
        <taxRegistrationId>**********</taxRegistrationId>
        <taxRegistrationAuthority>
            <country>DE</country>
        </taxRegistrationAuthority>
        <taxRegistrationType>VAT</taxRegistrationType>
    </member>
</TaxRegistrationDetails>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right at all, after two months the support is still bouncing me, it's very frustrating, they also made us re-fill the submission, we had full access, but since we were integrating since 2014, they forced us to resubmit just to answer the question, and even if they did not answer, they were going to remove our permissions if we did not. Very disappointing and not expected from a company like Amazon.